Implementing a Bootstrap Collapse "read more" without absolute heights
This snippet should show a horizontal Bootstrap card containing a .collapse which uses min- and max-height to implement a partial collapse. (Please run in full page mode in case scrollbars don't allow the card's vertical height to be shown):


.collapse.collapse-partial.collapse-mh-parent:not(.show) {
    max-height: 200px !important;
    overflow:   hidden;
  
    display:    -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}

.collapse-partial.collapse-mh-parent.collapsing {
    min-height: 200px !important;
}

button.collapse-partial.collapsed:after  {
    content: '+ Read More';
}

button.collapse-partial:not(.collapsed):after {
    content: '- Read Less';
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
   <div class="row g-0">
      <div class="col-4">
         <div class="bg-black position-relative mh-inherit rounded-start" style="">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x700/000/fff" alt="suede" class="card-img-top img-fluid opacity-6 mh-inherit" style="object-fit: cover;object-position: center;">
            <div class="card-img-overlay text-white d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between">
               <h1 class="card-title text-white mb-0">suede</h1>
               <div class="text-white">
                  <button class="btn icon-md bg-dark bg-opacity-75 text-white rounded-circle m-1"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
                  <div class="dropdown icon-md">
                     <button class="btn icon-md bg-dark bg-opacity-75 text-white rounded-circle m-1" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="Add tracks to playlist"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                     
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
         <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-between h-100">
            <div id="artist-info" class="d-flex flex-grow-1 text-center text-md-start flex-column align-items-center overflow-hidden collapse collapse-partial collapse-mh-parent">
               <div class="mb-1">
                  <div class="row justify-content-center">
                     <div class="col-auto">
                        <a href="/genre/GLAM%20ROCK" class="nav-link badge bg-success bg-opacity-10 text-success mb-2 fw-bold">GLAM ROCK</a>
                        <a href="/genre/POP%2FROCK" class="nav-link badge bg-success bg-opacity-10 text-success mb-2 fw-bold">POP/ROCK</a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="mb-3 text-center">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                     <button class="btn btn-info-soft btn-xs" type="button">Unrated</button>                     
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="mb-1">
                  English alternative rock band from London formed in 1989, disbanded 2003.<br>
                  Reunited in 2010 for a series of concerts, the band released four studio albums and two live albums since then.<br>
                  <br>
                  Due to legal issues, the band releases its records under the name "The London Suede" in the USA.
                  English alternative rock band from London formed in 1989, disbanded 2003.<br>
                  Reunited in 2010 for a series of concerts, the band released four studio albums and two live albums since then.<br>
                  <br>
                  Due to legal issues, the band releases its records under the name "The London Suede" in the USA.
                  English alternative rock band from London formed in 1989, disbanded 2003.<br>
                  Reunited in 2010 for a series of concerts, the band released four studio albums and two live albums since then.<br>
                  <br>
                  Due to legal issues, the band releases its records under the name "The London Suede" in the USA.
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
               <button class="btn btn-info-soft btn-xs collapse-partial collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#artist-info" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="artist-info">           
               </button>            
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>



Currently I have to set the heights with absolute px values. However, this means that the .collapse area doesn't naturally fill its area.
How can I, by default, get the .collapse-partial to fill all vertical space?
When Read more is clicked the card should expand vertically to show all the content. The image should not resize.

The text should not overlap the image - the "Read more" button should be inline with the bottom of the image (as it is in the example code).

The whole point of this is to make the UI more responsive by not specifying heights - the text should just fit into whatever space is made available (and not overflow it).

why don't you use lh units ?

you can also use fit-content and place excessive text in a div for show/hide use...

@MisterJojo probably because I've never heard of them ;-) how would they help here?

Personally I think that reading documentation can be very useful, don't you? But I understand you, today the documentation is written without any stylistic respect; I really miss those of Scott Knaster.

Where and how would fit-content be used? The text is already in a div. There are a lot of elements here so I think you might have to be a bit more specific how these solutions apply.


Where and how would fit-content be used? ...



const 
  textContent = document.querySelector('#text-Content')
, btnReadMore = document.querySelector('#btn-read-More')
  ;
btnReadMore.onclick =_=> textContent.classList.toggle('noMore');
#btn-read-More::after {
  content : 'read Less...'
  }
#text-Content.noMore + #btn-read-More::after {
  content : 'read more...'
  }
#text-Content  {
  height  : fit-content;
  }
#text-Content.noMore > span {
  display : none; 
  }
<div id="text-Content" class="noMore">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam.
  <span>
    Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. 
  </span>
</div>
<button id="btn-read-More"></button>




This works but is not relevant to the question. It imposes a different HTML element structure which I don't want - the whole point of avoiding absolute height declarations in the question is to make the UI responsive.

@DanGravell In this case why did you ignore my first post advocating relative unity?

I didn't - I responded how would they help here? (I guess it might have been ambiguous that I was responding to the fit-content comment - apologies if so). As I don't know how they work (as I wrote), I don't know how they would help and how they would be used.

@DanGravell Finaly I think I'm having trouble understanding (and translate) what you write, what get the .collapse-partial to fill all vertical space? means ? and in this case, why did you need a read less/more button ? (can't you write in globish as any body there? ;) )

Thanks for your time - I added some screenies that hopefully show it.

@DanGravell Ah thank you :), that’s much clearer. But sorry, for me this cannot be solved without using javascipt code...
